# deep merge mysql result set in php

Tags: php

Hello to all my dear friends

I have a result set from a MySQL database from a **multi-table join** that contains a lot of **duplicate data** (*not duplicate rows*)

and my goal is to convert this result set into a **summarized** form.

(to be able to create a loop and display its data on the client side in a simpler way)

I would be grateful if you could guide me on the best way to do this.

- Should I optimize the database query?
- Is it better to do this summarization on the server side and by PHP?
- Or is it better to do this on the client side using JavaScript?

my result set :

```
                        $result = array(
                            0=>array('username'=>'jack','ordercode'=>1,'productName'=>'x'),
                            1=>array('username'=>'jack','ordercode'=>1,'productName'=>'y'),
                            2=>array('username'=>'jack','ordercode'=>2,'productName'=>'z'),
                            3=>array('username'=>'steven','ordercode'=>3,'productName'=>'g'),
                            4=>array('username'=>'steven','ordercode'=>3,'productName'=>'j'),
                    );
```

and my ideal result set :

```
                        $result = array(
                           0=>array(
                            'username'=>array(
                                    'jack'=>array(
                                            'ordername'=>array(
                                                    '1'=>array(
                                                            'x','y'
                                                    ),'2'=>array(
                                                            'z'
                                                            )
                                                    )
                                    ),'steven'=>array(
                                            'ordername'=>array(
                                                    '3'=>array(
                                                            'g','j'
                                                            )
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    ))
                    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `foreach` like:

```
$result = [
  ['username' => 'jack', 'ordercode' => 1, 'productName' => 'x'],
  ['username' => 'jack', 'ordercode' => 1, 'productName' => 'y'],
  ['username' => 'jack', 'ordercode' => 2, 'productName' => 'z'],
  ['username' => 'steven', 'ordercode' => 3, 'productName' => 'g'],
  ['username' => 'steven', 'ordercode' => 3, 'productName' => 'j'],
];
$final = [];
foreach($result as $arr) {
  $final['username'][$arr['username']]['ordername'][$arr['ordercode']][] = $arr['productName'];
}
print_r($final);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [username] => Array
        (
            [jack] => Array
                (
                    [ordername] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => x
                                    [1] => y
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => z
                                )

                        )

                )

            [steven] => Array
                (
                    [ordername] => Array
                        (
                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => g
                                    [1] => j
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Reference:

- [Fiddle](https://onlinephp.io/c/9acd0)
- [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: I approved your answer but I can't upvote it because I don't have enough reputation for it. thanks.